# implementing RngCore for my own rng, with function returning result

Tags: rust

I have a usecase where I need to implement my own rng that can be passed to my function that require a RngCore rng.
So I need to implemennt the RngCore trait for my rng, that's running on a esp32 device.
What I have currently looks like this:

```
impl RngCore for HRNG {
    fn next_u32(&mut self) -> u32 {
        let mut n : u32;
        unsafe {
           let n = esp_idf_sys::esp_random();
        }
        n
    }

    fn next_u64(&mut self) -> u64 {
        let mut n : u32;
        unsafe {
           let n = esp_idf_sys::esp_random();
        }
        n
    }

    fn fill_bytes(&mut self, dest: &mut [u8]) {

        unsafe { esp_idf_sys::esp_fill_random(dest.as_ptr() as *mut core::ffi::c_void, dest.len().try_into().unwrap()); }
    }

    fn try_fill_bytes(&mut self, dest: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(), Error> {
        //
    }
    }
```

My issue is with the `try_fill_bytes` method.
It returns a result, that can be an error.
And currenlty the code gives me this issue:

```
the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

But I need to implement the trait, so I'm not sure what to do, since the function signature is required?

How do I actually get to implement this trait?

Comment: FWIW your `u64` implementation looks way wrong and I assume it doesn't compile. As it documents, `rand` also contains a bunch of guidance and helpers which allow implementing just one of the four methods of the trait. Since [the documentation for `esp_fill_random`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/random.html#_CPPv415esp_fill_randomPv6size_t) indicates that it's implemented in terms of `esp_random`, I think it'd make sense to implement just `next_u32`, then follow guidance to implement the others from this base.

Comment: That is [use `next_u64_via_u32`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_core/impls/fn.next_u64_via_u32.html) for `next_u64`, [`fill_bytes_via_next`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_core/impls/fn.fill_bytes_via_next.html) for `fill_bytes`, and implement `try_fill_bytes` as just `Ok(self.fill_bytes(dest))` since `esp_random` and `esp_fill_random` have no way to report failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`rand::Error`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/struct.Error.html), not ([implicitly `dyn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html)) [`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html).